# Give a unique name to multiple files with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm trying to learn multiprocessing library. This way it's working:

```
def generate_files(file_number, directory):
    var02 = str(int(100*random.random()))
    with open(f"{directory}/sample{file_number}.csv", "w") as f:
        f.write(var02)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    N1 = 100
    # create directory for samples
    directory = "samples"
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    cpu_count = int(os.environ["NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS"]) # doesn't work on mac
    # generate using all cores
    for i in range(N1):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=generate_files, args=[i, directory])
        process.start()
```

The bad thing is that program creates 100 processes. I'd like to limit them to `cpu_count`. So it should look something like this:

```
for i in range(cpu_count):
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=generate_files, args=[i, directory, cpu_count])
```

But this way all processes are trying to write to the same file, as names are the same. It's also not perfect if number of files is not multiple of cores. Any way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `multiprocessing`'s [pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) with the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) function. You can specifiy how many processes to use inside your pool (the dfault is `os.cpu_count`) and then run a function on each element of an iterable. So in your case you could do something like:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
import random

# create directory for samples
directory = "samples"

def generate_files(file_number):
    var02 = str(int(100*random.random()))
    with open(f"{directory}/sample{file_number}.csv", "w") as f:
        f.write(var02)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    N1 = 100

    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)

    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(generate_files, range(N1))
```

Comment: Good one, but I don't understand how it is supposed to create file names? Thanks, I figured it out.

Comment: what do you mean? the Pool is created with some number of worker processes, and then the `map` runs the `generate_files` function on all elements of the iterable `range(N1)` which is all numbers and thus creating all wanted files

Comment: Thank you :) Now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. First I need to create a list of file names, and finish the work as it's empty.

```
def generate_files(N2, file_numbers, directory):
    while file_numbers:
        file_number = file_numbers.pop()
    var02 = str(int(100*random.random()))
    with open(f"{directory}/sample{file_number}.csv", "w") as f:
        f.write(var02)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    N1 = 100
    nums = [e for e in range(100)]
    # create directory for samples
    directory = "samples"
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    cpu_count = int(os.environ["NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS"]) # doesn't work on mac
    # generate using all cores
    for i in range(cpu_count):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=generate_files, args=[N2, nums, directory])
        process.start()
```